# Vimscript: how to get the current list of user-defined functions and determine the files they are sourced from

Tags: vim

Is there a way I can query from within Vim information about user-defined vimscript functions and script files that Vim knows about?

The things I'd like to know are:

- Is a particular function defined?
- Which source file is a given function defined in?
- What are the vimscript files that have been sourced?

Etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> - Is a particular function defined?

Use the [exists](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#exists()) function:

```
:echo exists("*funcname")
```

> - Which source file is a given function defined in?

Unfortunately, there's no straight-forward way to do this.  You would have to parse the output of `:verbose function`.

> - What are the vimscript files that have been sourced?

Again, there's no straight-forward way to do this.  You would have to parse the output of `:scriptnames`.

What's the big picture for what you're trying to do that made you ask these questions?  There may be a better way to achieve it without needing answers to each question.

Comment: A very belated thank you for the answer. The big picture was that I was getting errors from 3rd party scripts, and was trying to debug them - I have since fixed the issue.

Comment: `vim -e -c 'verbose function | q' | grep pattern` or the like makes searching a little easier.